# Нужна ли запятая после союза "и" и перед союзом "пока"?

Tags: пунктуация

Я вышел на улицу, и (,)пока светило солнце, все радовались. 
Нужна ли перед "пока" запятая?
Очень нужно
Срочно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вышел на улицу, и, **пока светило солнце**, все радовались.

**Запятая нужна** на стыке сочинительного и подчинительного союзов, так как придаточное с союзом ПОКА можно переставить.

[Розенталь. § 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Основанием для такой пунктуации служит то обстоятельство, что вторую придаточную часть можно изъять из текста или переставить в другое место — в конец сложноподчиненного предложения.

В то же время семантика предложения не кажется ясной, для понимания ситуации нужен контекст.